# Linker script notation for handling unspecified sections

Tags: ld, static-linking, linker-scripts

I have an object file that has a bunch of compiler-generated sections I don't care about. When I link together a flat binary using a linker script, I can sometimes see these sections placed at the start or end of my binary. For example, if I have the linker script:

```
SECTIONS {
  __START = .;
  .text : { *(.text) }  /* I want all .text to go at the very start. */
  .data : { *(.data) }  /* Followed by .data. */
  /* Every other section can go somewhere here. */
  __END = ;.
}
```

Then it's possible for a section like `.interp` or `.note.gnu.build-id` to be placed at the start of the binary when I really want `.text` to be at the start. I can work around this by placing these sections at the end via:

```
SECTIONS {
  __START = .;
  .text : { *(.text) }  /* I want all .text to go at the very start. */
  .data : { *(.data) }  /* Followed by .data. */
  /* Every other section can go somewhere here. */
  .interp : { *(.interp) }
  __END = ;.
}
```

or somehow getting the compiler to just not emit that section at all, but I don't want to manually do this for every section I don't knowingly account for. **Is there a way to kinda just "glob" all sections I don't specify at the end of the binary?**